# How do you redirect to a page on a certain browser?

Tags: browser, redirection

To elaborate:
I need a way to redirect to a different page for google chrome, safari, firefox, etc.
as in (example only): you go into google.com on safari, then you get redirected to a page where it tells you to get google chrome, while if you go to google.com with google chrome, it doesn't redirect you to the "get google chrome" page.
is this possible? and if it is, can this be done with mobile browsers also?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you asking how Google does it?  How you can do it with your own web page?  How you can get you browser to go somewhere else (and what range of conditions)?

Comment: If you're talking about creating your own webpage that does this, then it is programming. It can be done with languages such as php, perl, asp, but SuperUser is not a "please write me a script" kind of site. If it is a local software solution, I think it can be circumvented, which is also not what you want. I'm therefor going to assume this is programming and thus should be posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @LPChip No my question was if there was a general line of code to do it, and i would figure out the rest on my own. but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @fixer1234 Basically how can I do it with my own webpage, yes

Comment: This *might* be suitable for Webmasters Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have your program look at the User Agent header - header which the client sends when making the initial request, then output an appropriate header to do a redirect.

A trivial variant using PHP - (untested code) would be something like

```
<?php
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='Chrome') )     
       header ("Location: http://www.get.mozilla.com");
    elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='Firefox'))
       header ("Location: http://www.get.chrome.com");
    .
    .
 ?>
```

Some Common User Agent strings can be found [here](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/CommonUserAgents).

And yes, this can be done with mobile user agents - although it is easy to fake if someone wants to.